# Mysql multi join with count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

have 3 tables

*product_tags*

```
product_id | tag
___________________
50         | new
50         | blac
66         | new
50         | green
111        | new
111        | white
```

*products_to_categories*

```
product_id | category_id
____________________
50         | 69
50         | 68
111        | 40
111        | 70
```

*categories*

```
category_id | parent_id (parent category id)
____________________
68         | 0
69         | 68
70         | 68
```

need **all tags** sorted by popularity (count product) within category 68 and its all subcategories (all categories with parent id 68)

my start query give wrong result

```
SELECT tag 
FROM product_tags opd 
  LEFT JOIN products_to_categories optc ON optc.product_id = opd.product_id 
  LEFT JOIN categories optx ON optx.parent_id = '68' 
WHERE opd.tag <> '' 
  AND optx.parent_id = '68' 
ORDER BY optc.product_id DESC
```

Result I need

```
tags
_____
new (2)
white (1)
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Your question is not quite clear...

Comment: no I have wrong result. My query is wrong and did not give tags from chosen category and child subcategories

Comment: @S.M.Nat check my adapted answer

Comment: correct answer `SELECT tag, COUNT(*) AS Num
FROM product_tags
    LEFT JOIN products_to_categories ON product_tags.product_id = products_to_categories.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN categories ON products_to_categories.category_id  = categories.category_id
WHERE product_tags.tag <> '' AND categories.parent_id = '68' OR categories.category_id = '68'
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY Num DESC
LIMIT 10`

Comment: Why do you exclude 'blac' and 'green' from your results? Both are tags of products in category 68.

Comment: What gave you the idea that you must outer join the tables? The common join is the inner join. Outer joins are only used in certain situations. Maybe you should look up joins in your SQL book again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this step by step. Use `EXISTS` or `IN` when checking whether a record exists. You want product_ids that are in the set of category_ids 68 and its children:

```
select tag, count(*)
from product_tags
where product_id in
(
  select product_id
  from products_to_categories
  where category_id = 68
  or category_id in
  (
    select category_id
    from categories
    where parent_id = 68
  )
)
group by tag
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `Join` on categories was incorrect. It should be:

```
 LEFT JOIN categories optx ON optx.parent_id = optc.category_id
```

Then to get the correct `count()` you should do a `GROUP BY` tag:

```
SELECT CONCAT(opd.tag, ' (', count(*), ')' )
FROM product_tags opd 
  LEFT JOIN products_to_categories optc ON optc.product_id = opd.product_id 
  LEFT JOIN categories optx ON optx.parent_id = optc.category_id 
WHERE opd.tag <> '' 
  AND optx.parent_id = '68' 
GROUP BY opd.tag
```

Comment: It's impossible to be sure at this stage but logically I think the JOIN between categories and product_to_categories should be on the category_id not the parent_id.

Comment: thank you for help but it give me NULL and error _Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available._

Comment: @S.M.Nat sorry buddy but my query is correct and works fine, at least it returns what you asked for. Either I completely missed it which I doubt, or the issue is on your side. Check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b92d7/2)

Comment: @SteveMoore your initial  query in my fiddle linked above returned an error, mine worked fine + I have the CONCAT that user asked  ;-)  no worries thought

Comment: thank you. Server error I believe my mysql version bug

Answer (score 1):

I think your biggest problem is that you are getting confused with your data and how it pieces together. I have rewritten your query removing your aliases so that you can clearly see what is happening with your joins.

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(*) AS Num
FROM product_tags
    LEFT JOIN products_to_categories ON product_tags.product_id = product_to_categories.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN categories ON product_to_categories.category_id  = categories.category_id
WHERE product_tags.tag <> '' AND categories.parent_id = '68'
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY Num DESC
```

I would then use your presentation layer to handle the presentation of your data "New (2)" etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you +1. This helps me almost 99%. The one missing - I want also get tags from root/parent category. Your great sql query result tags from child categories only

Comment: I found solution `OR categories.category_id = '68'`

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You are trying to outer join which makes no sense. It would even lead to incorrect results, had you outer-joined properly (your WHERE clause, however, turns your joins into mere inner joins). Then you are not considering category 68 itself, but only its children. And at last you are counting products multifold; if a product belongs to three child categories of 68, you are counting it thrice.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have a problem with your tables, because you can't do the difference between products id `50` and `111`, so, I advise you to move the `category_id` in `product_tags` table.

Comment: Please can you provide an example of what you mean as I am struggling to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you add column category_id to product_tag table you can do this query: select count(*) as tag_counter, tag from Product_tags 
where category_id in 
(select category_id from Category where category_id = 68 or parent_id = 68)
group by tag    --> and you can have the result wanted and you can drop the product_to_category table.